# Uncaught TypeError in Sales Shipment view

Tags: error

Running Magento 2.2.9.  After the upgrade from 2.2.8 this has started and I can't seem to figure it out. This happens when you try to view the shipment:

You see the formatted data and then this error:

> Fatal error: Uncaught TypeError: Argument 1 passed to
> Magento\Framework\DataObject::__construct() must be of the type array,
> null given, called in
> /var/www/vendor/magento/module-shipping/view/adminhtml/templates/order/packaging/packed.phtml
> on line 14 and defined in
> /var/www/vendor/magento/framework/DataObject.php:38 Stack trace: #0
> /var/www/vendor/magento/module-shipping/view/adminhtml/templates/order/packaging/packed.phtml(14):
> Magento\Framework\DataObject->__construct(NULL) #1
> /var/www/vendor/magento/framework/View/TemplateEngine/Php.php(59):
> include('/var/www/vendor...') #2
> /var/www/vendor/magento/framework/View/Element/Template.php(270):
> Magento\Framework\View\TemplateEngine\Php->render(Object(Magento\Shipping\Block\Adminhtml\Order\Packaging\Interceptor),
> '/var/www/vendor...', Array) #3
> /var/www/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(58):
> Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template->fetchView('/var/www/vendor...')
>
> ## 4 /var/www/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(138):
>
> Magento\Shipping\Bloc in
> /var/www/vendor/magento/framework/DataObject.php on line 38

I'm not sure what's going on. Any help would be great.